# Какая тема используется на stackblitz.com

Tags: visual-studio-code, phpstorm, atom

Может кто то знает, это за тема? стоит на сайте https://stackblitz.com/ по умолчанию. Есть в vscode несколько подобных но все равно не один в один.Может кто то с подобной работает и узнает на глаз.
[image]

Comment: Вообще похоже на стандартную темную тему, но могу ошибаться

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел в итоге после пару заходов поиска,может кто то когда то будет искать. Тема называется Dark+(default dark) если искать в vscode.